# Configuring custom network in the Directions dijit?

Tags: javascript, network-analyst, dojo, configurable-map-viewer

I'm making a CMV app and trying to make the directions widget work with my own network dataset. I replaced ESRI's street route network service with my own service, so `viewer.js` looks something like this:

```
directions: {
    include: true,
    id: 'directions',
    type: 'titlePane',
    path: 'gis/dijit/Directions',
    title: 'Directions',
    open: false,
    position: 7,
    options: {
        map: true,
        mapRightClickMenu: true,
        options: {
            routeTaskUrl: 'https://domain.com/arcgis/rest/services/my_network/NAServer/Route',
            routeParams: {
                directionsLanguage: 'en-US',
                directionsLengthUnits: units.MILES
            }                         
        }
    }
```

The app is not using my custom network. I get no results when using the widget--any suggestions as I troubleshoot?

I know the network service is working properly, as I got it to work in ESRI's stand-alone example [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000002pn000000).

Comment: Help people to help you. Please create fiddler so that people can debug it or post browser console errors.

Answer (score 0):

The CMV Directions widget is a wrapper for Esri's [Directions widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/directions-amd.html). You can test your own service using this [example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/widget_directions_basic.html). The example also demonstrates the use of a proxy. Depending on the location of your service, you may need to do that as well.